# Calculate fractional difference between columns in two Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to calculate the fractional difference between >20 columns in two DataFrames for rows with same value in a different column.

For example given two dataframes:

```
df1 = index, A, B, C, D, ID
        0,   2, 1, 5, 4, -2
        1,   1, 2, 2, 4, -1
        2,   2, 4, 8, 8,  0 
        3,   1, 4, 6, 5,  1

df2 = index, A, B, C, D, ID
        0,   2, 1, 2, 2, -3
        1,   4, 3, 3, 2, -2
        2,   6, 2, 4, 6,  -1 
        3,   1, 4, 2, 4,  0
```

And for each column (A-D), I would like to get the fractional difference (i.e. `df3['A'] = (df1['A']-df2['A'])/df1['A']`) if the row has the same value for the ID. There may be rows in either dataframe that don't have common IDs and those rows should not be included in df3.

Desired Output:

```
df3 = index,  A,  B,   C,   D,  ID
        0,   -1,  -2, 0.4, 0.5, -2 
        1,   -5,  0,  -1,  -0.5, -1
        2,   0.5, 0, 0.75, 0.5,  0
```

Eventually I would also like to get the sum squared of these fractional differences for every row for columns A-D in df3 (i.e. 32.72 for the example shown)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to set `ID` as index on both dataframes, and then you can take the difference of the dataframes directly. The code below will accomplish what you are looking for:

**Sample Data**

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
        [[0,   2, 1, 5, 4, -2],
        [1,   1, 2, 2, 4, -1],
        [2,   2, 4, 8, 8,  0 ],
        [3,   1, 4, 6, 5,  1]], columns = ['index', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'ID'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
        [[0,   2, 1, 2, 2, -3],
        [1,   4, 3, 3, 2, -2],
        [2,   6, 2, 4, 6,  -1 ],
        [3,   1, 4, 2, 4,  0]], columns = ['index', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'ID'])
```

**Fractional Differencing**

```
df1 = df1.set_index('ID') # set index for fractional differencing
df2 = df2.set_index('ID') # set index for fractional differencing
target_cols = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'] # define columns to use in differencing
df3 = (df1[target_cols] - df2[target_cols]) / df1[target_cols] # get fractional difference
df3 = df3.dropna().reset_index() # remove row observations without intersecting IDs in df1 and df2
```

**Output**

```
print(df3.to_string())
   ID     A     B     C     D
0  -2 -1.00 -2.00  0.40  0.50
1  -1 -5.00  0.00 -1.00 -0.50
2   0  0.50  0.00  0.75  0.50
```

Comment: Good answer, maybe make your last line `df3.dropna().reset_index()` to get expected output. Besides that +1